# Sum on a dynamic list that has ExpandoObject as items

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dynamic

I have a dynamic list with ExpandoObject as items :

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (...)
{
    var dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

    ...
    list.Add(dynamicObject);
}
```

How can I use .Sum() on a dynamic list ? I know the names of the properties 
of that list , but `Sum()` does not take a string as argument .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have list like this:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>
{
    new ExpandoObject(),
    new ExpandoObject(),
    new ExpandoObject(),
};

list[0].Foo = 1;
list[1].Foo = 2;
list[2].Foo = 3;
```

you can use `ExpandoObject`'s properties as regular properties, if their names are known at compile-time:

```
var sum1 = list
    .Sum(item => item.Foo);
```

or use dictionary syntax, if property names are known at run-time only:

```
var sum2 = list
    .Sum(item => (int)((IDictionary<string, object>)item)["Foo"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To my mind you could try this :

```
 var listSum = list.Sum(item => item.GetType().GetProperty("propertyName").GetValue());
```

I called list the list on which you want to call the Sum method.

Let me know if the result is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sum(Func<TSource, int> selector)`

For you example :

```
        var values = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            var dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
            dynamicObject[value.ToString()] = value;
            list.Add(dynamicObject);
        }
        // Kind of ugly as cast but otherwise it has trouble to find the Count property
        var result = list.Sum(x => (x as IDictionary<string, Object>).Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
        Console.ReadLine();
```